# What is MVC? and what UI does it use?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I see a lot of jobs asking for MVC experience.
I am assuming the roles are talking about asp.net MVC as they are generally .NET jobs I have been looking at.
A few questions:
1.Generally when people say MVC are they talking about it as a general design pattern or as asp.net MVC? is it important to be specific here?
2.What is the UI in asp.net MVC? is it just razor views? is webforms another option? blazor? Can other UI's like javascript frameworks be used?
3. Typically when a job is asking for MVC experience what are they asking for? razor views experience? is this different in a .Net context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Generally, MVC is a design pattern. Every tech stack has specific
   frameworks to support that design pattern. Asp.Net MVC for .Net,
   Spring MVC for Java. etc.

   If you are talking about job descriptions, yes, it is important to
   be a specific framework. Net developers will be interested in using
   Asp.Net MVC. Java developers will be interested in using Spring
   MVC.etc. The concept is similar. The difference is the knowledge of
   using these frameworks.
2. UI in asp.net MVC can be Razor, blazor or javascript frameworks
   (Angular, ReactJs..etc). For webforms, since MVC is a design
   pattern, of course, we can implement MVC with webforms too. However,
   we need to custom a lot for implementation of Models/Controllers...The
   webform was designed to bring the concept of windows form to the
   web. It does not support MVC by default.
3. It depends on the job and the projects they are working on whether
   they require Asp.Net MVC with razor views or javascript frameworks
   (Angular, ReactJS) as views.

   There are different implementations of views in Asp.Net MVC. Some projects will use Razor for views, others will use Angular for examples. Usually, for .Net developer roles, they will expect you know at least one of them or be able to learn them.